# Reload BufferImage Data when file changes

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, pixel

I been trying to figure out a way to re-load an image after it has suffer changes. For that I create a refresh button and my plan is, when clicking in this "reload" button re-load the original image so that we can see the new alterations that the file suffer(from an external software like W10 paint).

[image]

I tried quite a few things, one of them was using the flush method to attemp to reload the image, but to not avail.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ApplicationView1();
    }

    static class ApplicationView1 extends JFrame{
        JButton btnReload;
        ImagePanel imagePanel;

        public ApplicationView1() throws IOException {
            initComponents();
            addEventListeners();

            setTitle("Pokemon Tile Creator");
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 360));
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);
            pack();
        }

        private void initComponents() throws IOException {
            btnReload = new JButton("Reload");
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Florest_PixelArt.png"));
            imagePanel = new ImagePanel(bufferedImage);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(btnReload, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        private void addEventListeners() {
            btnReload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        imagePanel.image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Florest_PixelArt.png"));
                        repaint();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    static class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
        public BufferedImage image;

        public ImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason if I select the image throught a filechoser, the image gets reloaded correctly;_;

Comment: "For some reason if I select the image throught a filechoser, the image gets reloaded correctly;_; " so does that answer your question? If so, please delete what you've posted here

Comment: No it does not;_; I dont want to use a filechoser everytime i want the image to get updated.

Comment: Maybe try to call ImageIO.read(new FIle("C:/Florest_PixelArt.png")); in your "addEventListener". Also I am not sure if this is intentional, but your reload button doesn't seem to have a purpose as there is no direct call "btnReload.addActionListener()" somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  The ImageIO.read fixed the problem.